# Infdig in Angular when trying to calculate timestamp from date for $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest, angularjs-infdig

I get a date value in my controller and I want to have the timestamp value in a $scope variable.

I do `$scope.timestamp = new Date(workspace.date).getTime();`

But I get error messages in console:

> angular.js:63 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest()
>   iterations reached. Aborting!(…)

How can I avoid digest loop here?

Comment: where did you set above code? inside any iteration?

Comment: No, it's just a line of code which should be called only one time.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the line of code you mention is causing that error message. This is usually a sign of using an old version of Angular (where you had to concern yourself with the digest cycle). Most of that is automatic now.

Comment: Thanks Joel, its 1.4. It only happens, when this line of code is there.

Comment: You may have this line directly in controller, you can not have it in $watch, any function you call from html, etc.

Comment: yes, it's only in main controller ... without function, without watcher.